# Is there a way to access the top left corner push button of QTableView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

PyQt 4.11.4
Qt 4.8.7

Is there a way to get a pointer to the top left corner cell/pushbutton on a QTableView?  I would like to remove it or hide it. In the image below its the cell left of the first column (Lag1_Lvl_Cng_BBB_Spread) and above the first row (qadj_disp_inc_nom)

Any help appreciated[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "top right corner cell/pushbutton". Perhaps a screenshot with a circle or arrow would help.

Comment: Are you talking about the [corner button](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#cornerButtonEnabled-prop) - which is at the top left rather than top right?

Comment: Yeah sorry, top left!

Comment: So what's wrong with `setCornerButtonEnabled(False)`, like @eclarkso suggested?

Comment: @titusjan I want to remove it.  Not just disable it

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above, you can only disable it via [`::setCornerButtonEnabled()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#cornerButtonEnabled-prop).

That said, if this is important enough you can try [hackery referenced in this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28693-QTableWidget-Using-top-left-corner-cell) to hide or style or otherwise muck up the button.